# Is it possible to get time difference between two lat and lng?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geo

I have a couple of gps latitudes and longitudes.

Where some gps have a timestamp associated with latitudes and longitudes but some dont.

so is there a way to get timestamp for those latitudes and longitudes that dont have timestamps associated with them?

for eg: latitudes and longitudes are like this:

```
24 deg 12' 11.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W (2020:02:02 01:19:08.111)
24 deg 12' 12.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 13.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 14.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 15.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 16.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 17.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 18.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 19.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 20.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W
24 deg 12' 21.14" N - 10 deg 20' 23.45" W (2020:02:02 01:49:08.111)
```

I would like to find the time difference for lat&lng with atleast almost correct if not absolutely correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Comment: What does the "location" and "timestamp" represent? (For example: If they describe an object moving at constant speed, you can linearly interpolate between the timestamps).